# image watermark doesn't work

Tags: php, image, watermark

I am trying to add a watermark to an uploaded image.
Unfortunately, I am getting this error: '

> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(upload/##.jpg): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in

I am using the code from php.net with some changes:

```
  // Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('logo.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: check your logo.png location, where it stores. It should be in the same directory where file is.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe make use of the `textPainter` class I created to print text over images:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/PHP-Backend/tree/master/textPainter

[Living demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/demos/writingOverImageFile.php)

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are passing wrong path of image `$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);` . check the value of $image and for test purpose copy both image in same directory and run the script.